# Check for a factory response then proceed the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have built a basic authentication factory that i inject in controllers to check if the user is logged in and return the user info if so. The problem is that whenever i try it i get a `false` return even if the user is logged in, as the controllers asks for the data and before getting response the factory finishes its process. I have to then reload the page in order for the controllers to be able to access the user info.

Here is the factory :

```
angular.module('moheera').factory('registerUserConfigFactory', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
   var _this = {};
   //Get the user info from the window element that has been injected in the index page on the server side
   _this.user = window.userInfo || false;
   //Update the user rootScope to be true
   if(_this.user){
      $rootScope.logged = true;
   }
   return _this;
}]);
```

and here is a controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('userModule').controller('profileUserControlller', ['registerUserConfigFactory', '$scope', function (registerUserConfigFactory, $scope) {
    $scope.userInfo = registerUserConfigFactory;   
}]);
```

I hope there is something i can do that won't require "promise" as this would be confusing in the controllers level. How can i achieve this?

i changed my mind .... i think it would be better to use the promises.

i have made this code , it works but i feel like it could be done better specially that i have to call it twice!!

```
'use strict';

angular.module('moheera').factory('registerUserConfigFactory', ['$window', '$rootScope', '$q', function ($window, $rootScope, $q) {
    //Get the user info from the window element that has been injected in the index page on the server side
    var _this = {};

    _this.user = false;

    _this.readUserInfo = function () {
        return  $window.userInfo || false;
    }

    //Update the user rootScope to be true
    _this.registerUser = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(_this.readUserInfo());
        deferred.promise.then(function (result) {
            _this.user = result;
            if(_this.user){
                $rootScope.logged = true;
            }
        });
    }

    return _this;
}]);
```

and here is the controller-side code:

```
registerUserConfigFactory.registerUser();
$scope.userInfo = registerUserConfigFactory;
```

here is the last update :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('moheera').factory('registerUserConfigFactory', ['$window', '$rootScope', '$q', function ($window, $rootScope, $q) {
    //Get the user info from the window element that has been injected in the index page on the server side
    var _this = {};

    _this.user = false;

    //Read user info
    _this.readUserInfo = function () {
        return _this.user = $window.userInfo || false;
    }

    //Clear user info from the browser and change the rootScope status to false
    _this.clearUserInfo = function () {
        $rootScope.logged = false;
        _this.user = $window.userInfo = false;
    }

    //register user info
    _this.setUser = function (user) {
        _this.user = $window.userInfo = user || false;
        if(_this.user){
            $rootScope.logged = true;
        }
    }

    //Get the user info
    _this.getUser = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(_this.readUserInfo());
        deferred.promise.then(function (result) {
            if(result){
                _this.user = result;
                $rootScope.logged = true;
            }
        });
        return _this.user;
    }

    return _this;
}]);
```

Comment: factories are singleton's so they get created only once.  so when your factory is initialized by angular, the `window.userInfo` has not yet been initialized so the _this.user will always be false

Comment: how can i solve this !??? , if there is a solution that dose not require "promises" that would be great ?!